# Trying to populate ASP GridView as it's data source gets populated on the server

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi I am new to using ASP.NET and GridView and it would be great if someone could kindly help me out here.

My scenario is that on a button click event, my code tries to get data from a webservice in chunks for a long period of time. Now I create a DataTable and populate it as each chunk is retrieved. My question is how do I show in gridview whatever I have retrieved so far before the button click returns ? Say, if I have three chunks being retrieved one after another then as of now the gridview gets populated with all the data from the 3 chunks at once, I want to be able to show the first chunk as it is downloaded, then add the second chunk and finally the third. Not sure how to do this.

I'd be happy if you just give me an overall solution/point me in the asp feature I should be using to get this done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Merge` the existing `DataTable` every time you receive a new chunk from the `Web service` and then bind the updated (Merged) DataTable to the gridview.

Check out this article from MSDN and get a better idea of how you can merge DataTables

[DataSet.Merge Method (DataTable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx)

Also look at this article that may help you in your current problem.

[Merging two Datasets into a single Datagrid](http://aspalliance.com/148_Merging_two_Datasets_into_a_single_Datagrid)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I sort of do the same thing now, but I don't make seperate postback calls for each chunk, a single postback call would span over downloading multiple chunks... It is during this single postbackcall that I want the gridview to show data as it arrives... makes sense?

Comment: hmm that could be an issue. What if you use AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding using webservice. Then asp:GridView will create unnecessary hassles for you as its designed for simple server side bindings.
Why dont you try [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), as they are much better alternatives?